# How to prevent new custom WebSphere Portal8.0 based theme from refreshing browser page when switching portal page?

Tags: javascript, dojo, themes, websphere-portal

I'm developing portlets with WebSphere Portal8.0 and am testing a new customized theme that is based on the Portal8.0 default theme having the Full profile.  I created four portal pages with each one displaying a single portlet.  The horizontal navigation menu at the top of the browser is the auto-generated navigation menu provided by the theme.   When I switch from one portal page to another, there is considerable lag time, about 5 seconds before I see any response in Firebug, and then the whole page goes blank for up to two seconds, and then finally loads the new page.  I expected only the body part of the browser that displays the contents of the current page to refresh, not the whole page including the header banner and navigation menu.  What could be causing this?

Is there a particular theme resource or configuration file that is causing this?  Could it be a setting in the Portal itself, separate from the theme?   I have the Firebug console open when testing and notice that the same dojo1.7 modules are reloaded each time.  Why aren't the dojo1.7 modules cached?  I verified from the Portal admin console that each portal page enables cacheing for 24hrs, and I also verified that each portlet itself also enables a 24hr cache.   I also verified that the Firefox browser has 250MB cache enabled.

I created and packaged the Portal8.0 based customized theme into a single WAR file.  In my customized theme, I have customized the theme_en.html, Default.jsp, and commonActions.jsp files.   I've begun trying to slowly revert the changes I made to each of those file with the hope that I'll discover the particular customization that is causing the significant lag, but so far am not seeing it.

Am I on the right track?  Could the lag be due to the customized theme files?  Here are the customized theme files:

theme_en.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
<!-- rel=dynamic-content indicates an element that is replaced with the contents produced by the specified href. 
  dyn-cs:* URIs are resolved using the WP DynamicContentSpotMappings resource environment provider. These values can
  also be set using theme metadata if a theme is specified in the URI (e.g. @tl:oid:theme_unique_name). -->
<link rel="dynamic-content" href="co:head">
<link rel="dynamic-content" href="dyn-cs:id:FpmThemeURS8_head">
<!-- rendering is delegated to the specified href for each locale -->
</head>
<!--  <body class="lotusui30dojo tundra locale_en">  --> 
<body class="jelam locale_en"> 
 <div class="wpthemeFrame">
  <header role="banner">
    <!-- inserts the managed pages preview mode contributions 
   <div class="wpthemeHeader">
    <a rel="dynamic-content" href="dyn-cs:id:80theme_preview"></a>

    <div class="wpthemeInner">
     <div class="wpthemeLogo wpthemeLeft">
      <span class="wpthemeAltText">IBM WebSphere Portal</span>
     </div>
     
    </div>
   </div>
 -->
   <!-- end header -->

   <!-- inserts the universal toolbar -->
   <a rel="dynamic-content" href="dyn-cs:id:80theme_toolbar"></a>
   
   <div class="wpthemeBanner">
    <div class="wpthemeBannerInner">
     <div class="wpthemeInner" style="width:100%;">
<!--        <a rel="dynamic-content" href="dyn-cs:id:80theme_search"></a>       --> 
       <a rel="dynamic-content" href="dyn-cs:id:FpmThemeURS8_commonActions"></a>
<!--       <a rel="dynamic-content" href="dyn-cs:id:80theme_commonActions"></a>   
       <a rel="dynamic-content" href="dyn-cs:id:80theme_mobileNav"></a>    
      <div class="wpthemeClear"></div>
-->
     </div>
    </div>
   </div><!--end main banner-->
   
   <div class="wpthemeBanner wpthemeBannerPrimaryNavigation">
    <div class="wpthemeBannerInner">
     <div class="wpthemeInner">
      <a rel="dynamic-content" href="dyn-cs:id:FpmThemeURS8_primaryNav"></a>
      <div class="wpthemeClear"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div><!--end primary nav banner-->
   
   <div class="wpthemeSecondaryBanner">
    <a rel="dynamic-content" href="dyn-cs:id:FpmThemeURS8_secondaryNav"></a>
    <div class="wpthemeClear"></div>
   </div><!--end secondary banner-->
  </header>

  <div class="wpthemeMainContent" role="main" >
   <div class="wpthemeInner"> 
    <!-- asa markup contributions for pages --> 
    <a rel="dynamic-content" href="dyn-cs:id:80theme_asa"></a>
<!--     <a rel="dynamic-content" href="dyn-cs:id:FpmThemeURS8_crumbTrail"></a>   -->
    <div class="wpthemeClear"></div>
    <a rel="dynamic-content" href="dyn-cs:id:FpmThemeURS8_status"></a>
   </div>  

   <!-- required - do not remove -->
   <a rel="dynamic-content" href="state.portlet:portlet?include=windowState&include=portletMode&mime-type=text/html"></a>
   
   <div id="layoutContainers" class="wpthemeLayoutContainers wpthemeLayoutContainersHidden" > 
    <div class="wpthemeInner">     
     <a rel="dynamic-content" href="dyn-cs:id:80theme_layout"></a>
     <div class="wpthemeClear"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div><!--end main content-->
  
  <footer class="wpthemeFooter" role="contentinfo">
   <div class="wpthemeInner"> 
    <a rel="dynamic-content" href="dyn-cs:id:FpmThemeURS8_footer"></a>
    <div class="wpthemeClear"></div>
   </div>
  </footer><!-- page footer -->
  
 </div><!-- end frame -->
  
    <!-- This is responsible for bootstrapping the configuration for the javascript framework. 
        This is located here instead of the head section to improve client performance. -->
 <div class="wpthemeComplementaryContent" id="wpthemeComplementaryContent" role="region" aria-labelledby="wpthemeComplementaryContentText">
  <span class="wpthemeAltText" id="wpthemeComplementaryContentText" >Complementary Content</span>
  <a rel="dynamic-content" href="co:config"></a>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.jsp:

```html
<%@ page session="false" buffer="none" %>
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<%-- Licensed Materials - Property of IBM, 5724-E76, (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2001, 2004, 2006, 2010 - All Rights reserved. --%> 
<%-- NOTE: By default, automatic reloading of theme and skin JSP files is turned off.
  To see the changes you make to this file without stopping and restarting
  the server, follow the instructions for enabling automatic JSP reloading
  in the InfoCenter.  Do not enable automatic JSP reloading in a production 
  environment because performance will decrease.
  NOTE: Default.jsp uses the @include JSP directive to include jsp fragments
  (denoted by the.jspf extension) which compiles these files into the servlet
  for Default.jsp. If you change these files, you must "touch" the version
  of Default.jsp which includes it to see your changes.
  You can do this by editing Default.jsp and saving it. --%> 
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<%@ include file="./includePortalTaglibs.jspf" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/portal-internal.tld" prefix="portal-internal" %>

<%@ page import="java.util.*,javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext"%>
<%@ page import="com.ibm.portal.um.exceptions.PumaException"%>
<%@ page import="com.ibm.portal.um.PumaHome"%>
<%@ page import="com.ibm.portal.um.PumaController"%>
<%@ page import="com.ibm.portal.um.PumaLocator"%>
<%@ page import="com.ibm.portal.um.Group"%>
<%@ page import="com.ibm.websphere.cache.DistributedMap"%>
<%@ page import="javax.portlet.PortletSession" %>

<%-- BEGIN GCO --%>
<%
    System.out.println("------------------------- COMPASS_THEME_URS: INSIDE Default.jsp 11:22");

  String currentVP = "urs"; 
  String vpPageTitle = "URS PORTAL"; // will be displayed just under banner at top of page to indicate to the user which virtual portal he is on
   String sessionId = request.getSession().getId();
  int PORTAL_TIMEOUT = request.getSession().getMaxInactiveInterval();
  PORTAL_TIMEOUT = PORTAL_TIMEOUT / 60;
  String firstName = null;
  String lastName = null;
  String userName = null;
  String dotNumber = null; 
  String uri = request.getRequestURI();

  // get the host - WebSphere_Portal or WebSphere_Portal_2 
  ServletContext sc = this.getServletContext();
  String portalServer = (String)sc.getAttribute("com.ibm.websphere.servlet.application.host");
  String portalIndicator = "&nbsp;"; // if node1 use one space
  if(portalServer != null) {
      if(portalServer.indexOf("2") != -1) {
          portalIndicator = "&nbsp;&nbsp;"; // if node2 use two spaces
      }
  }
  try {
        javax.naming.Context jndiContext = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
        DistributedMap dMap = (DistributedMap)jndiContext.lookup("services/cache/distributedmap");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("dMap",dMap);
        PumaHome ph = (PumaHome)jndiContext.lookup(PumaHome.JNDI_NAME);
        firstName = (String)dMap.get(sessionId+"firstName");
        lastName = (String)dMap.get(sessionId+"lastName");
        userName = (String)dMap.get(sessionId+"userName");
        PumaController pc = ph.getController();    
         dMap.put(sessionId+"themeName", "FpmThemeURS8");
         dMap.putAll(request.getParameterMap());
        if (firstName == null || lastName == null || userName == null) {
          List getThese = new ArrayList();
          getThese.add("uid");
          getThese.add("givenName");
          getThese.add("sn");
          Object userObj = pc.getCurrentUser();
          if(userObj != null) {
              Map userInfo = pc.getAttributes(pc.getCurrentUser(), getThese);
              Object val = userInfo.get("givenName");
              firstName = (String)(val instanceof List ? ((List)val).get(0) : val);
              val = userInfo.get("sn");
              lastName = (String)(val instanceof List ? ((List)val).get(0) : val);
              val = userInfo.get("uid");
              userName = (String)(val instanceof List ? ((List)val).get(0) : val);
              request.getSession().setAttribute("userFullName",firstName+" "+lastName);
              dMap.put(sessionId+"userFullName", firstName+" "+lastName);
    
              pageContext.setAttribute("userFullName",firstName+" "+lastName,PageContext.APPLICATION_SCOPE );
              System.out.println("FpmThemeURS8: sessionId="+sessionId+" setting userFullName='"+firstName+" "+lastName+"'");
              dMap.put(sessionId+"userName", userName);
            PumaLocator pl = (PumaLocator)ph.getLocator();
            List groups = pl.findGroupsByPrincipal(pc.getCurrentUser(), false);
            List getCn = new ArrayList();
            getCn.add("cn");
            Map groupAttrs = null;

            // only get the dotNumber from the POST, which prevents user from spoofing it in URL
            if(request.getMethod().toLowerCase().equals("post")) {
                dotNumber = request.getParameter("dotNumber"+sessionId.split("-")[0]);
            }

            if (dotNumber == null) {
              dotNumber = (String)dMap.get(sessionId+"dotNumber");
            } else {
                  dMap.put(sessionId+"dotNumber", dotNumber);
            }            
            System.out.println("FpmThemeURS8 Default.jsp dotNumber="+dotNumber);
            
            System.out.println("FpmThemeURS8 Default.jsp request.getMethod()="+request.getMethod());
            ArrayList<String> parameterNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            Enumeration enumeration = request.getParameterNames();
               while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                   String parameterName = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
                   System.out.println("FpmThemeURS8 Default.jsp parameterName="+parameterName);
                   parameterNames.add(parameterName);
               }
               
            
            dMap.put(sessionId+"currentVP", currentVP);
            
          }
        }
  } catch (javax.naming.NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("FpmThemeURS8: got naming exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (PumaException pe) {
        System.out.println("FpmThemeURS8: got puma exception");
        pe.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("FpmThemeURS8: got exception msg: "+ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("FpmThemeURS8: got exception class: "+ex.getClass());
        System.out.println("FpmThemeURS8: got exception localMsg: "+ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        System.out.println("FpmThemeURS8: got exception cause: "+ex.getCause());
        ex.printStackTrace();
  }
%>



<script src="/CompassThemesURS/themes/html/commonurs/js/dwrutil.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var displayedPortlets = new Array(); 
  var loadingCount = 0; // incremented/decremented by various portlets to keep user from attempting to load one record while another one is still loading.
  if( typeof(console) == "undefined"){
    console = new Object();
    console.debug = function(str){ var ignoreme; /* do nothing with these debug calls unless in Firefox */ };
    console.log = function(str){ var ignoreme; /* do nothing with these debug calls unless in Firefox */ };
    console.warn = function(str){ var ignoreme; /* do nothing with these debug calls unless in Firefox */ };
    console.info = function(str){ var ignoreme; /* do nothing with these debug calls unless in Firefox */ };
    console.error = function(str){ var ignoreme; /* do nothing with these debug calls unless in Firefox */ };
    console.dir = function(str){ var ignoreme; /* do nothing with these debug calls unless in Firefox */ };
  }
</script> 
<%-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CompassThemesURS/themes/html/commonurs/dojo/gridx-1.3.0/resources/claro/Gridx.css" /> --%>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CompassThemesURS/themes/html/commonurs/dojo/1.9.1/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CompassThemesURS/themes/html/commonurs/dojo/1.9.1/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css" />
<!-- load Dojo -->
<script>
var dojoConfig = {
    
    packages: [
               { name:'com', location:'/wps/themeModules/js/com' }, 
               { name:'ibm', location:'/wps/themeModules/js/ibm' }, 
        { name: "sizzle-master",  location: "/CompassThemesURS/themes/html/commonurs/sizzle-master" },
        { name: "commonjs", location: "/CompassThemesURS/themes/html/commonurs/js" }
    ]
};
</script>
<!-- switched async:true to async:false to allow legacy dojo.require function to work for WebSphere's portlet-client-model 
<script src="/CompassThemesURS/themes/html/commonurs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js"
               data-dojo-config="isDebug:true, parseOnLoad: false"></script>
-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="/CompassThemesURS/themes/html/commonurs/help/help.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CompassThemesURS/themes/html/commonurs/js/PortletPreference.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CompassThemesURS/themes/html/commonurs/js/compassportal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CompassThemesURS/themes/html/commonurs/js/CompassRefCodes.js"></script>
<script src="/CompassThemesURS/themes/html/commonurs/js/util.js"></script>
<%-- include a static copy of the DWR engine.js and UserProfileHelperDWR.js to enable cacheing of them --%>
<script src="/CompassThemesURS/themes/html/commonurs/js/engine.js"></script>

<%@ include file="./Dojo191CompassErrorHandler.jspf" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
var globalCeh = null;

<%-- require(["commonjs/CompassErrorHandler","dojo/_base/lang"], function(ceh, lang) {
     dwr.engine.setErrorHandler(ceh.compassErrorHandler);
     lang.setObject("global_ceh", ceh);
     globalCeh = ceh;
    });

function topInitializeErrHandler(dom, parser, lang) {
  dom.byId("errDialogDivWrapper").style.display = "block";
  
  console.debug("Default.jsp dojo parsing errDialogDivWrapper");
  parser.parse(dom.byId("errDialogDivWrapper")); 
}
--%>


</script>


<%-- END GCO --%>

<%--
--%><portal-core:constants/><portal-core:defineObjects/><portal-internal:adminNavHelper/><%@ 
include file="./bootstrap.jspf" %><%--
--%><%-- The theme template is determined by whether there is a value set in page meta data, 
if no value is set in the meta data, then it defaults to the template stored in webdav --%><%--
--%><c:choose><%--
--%><c:when test="${!empty themeTemplateURI}"><%--
--%><r:dataSource uri='<%="spa:" + pageContext.getAttribute("currentNavNodeID", PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE)%>' escape="none"><%--
 --%><r:param name="themeURI" value="${themeTemplateURI}"/><%--
 --%><r:param name="mime-type" value="text/html"/><%--
    --%><r:param name="max-age" value="2"/><%-- 
--%></r:dataSource><%--
--%></c:when><%-- If no theme template is found, the fallback.jsp is rendered
--%><c:otherwise><%@ include file="./fallback.jsp" %></c:otherwise><%--
--%></c:choose>
```

commonActions.jsp:

```html
<%@ page session="false" buffer="none" %> 
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/portal-internal.tld" prefix="portal-internal" %>
<%@ include file="../includePortalTaglibs.jspf" %>
<%@ include file="../helper.jspf" %>
<portal-core:constants/><portal-core:defineObjects/>

<link href="/CompassThemesURS/themes/html/COMPASS_THEME_URS/NewFMCSASite_ReportSafetyViolations_completeFiles_files/css_ZMBdu8p5DxuWg4wW2gmFGAh7WzeTX659AOzXt0fJQmU.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">
require(["commonjs/CompassErrorHandler","dojo/dom", "dojo/parser",
         "dojo/_base/lang","dijit/ProgressBar", "dojo/domReady!"], 
   function(ceh,  dom, parser, lang) {
     dwr.engine.setErrorHandler(ceh.compassErrorHandler);
     lang.setObject("global_ceh", ceh);
     globalCeh = ceh;
     topInitializeErrHandler(dom, parser, lang);
    });
    

function topInitializeErrHandler(dom, parser, lang) {
  dom.byId("errDialogDivWrapper").style.display = "block";
  
  console.debug("Default.jsp dojo parsing errDialogDivWrapper");
  parser.parse(dom.byId("errDialogDivWrapper")); 
}
    
    
</script>
    
<%-- Renders links for Login/Logout and Help that are shown in the banner --%>
<%-- The following variables are defined in bootstrap.jspf for performance reasons and reused here:
    * selectionPath
    * deviceClass
    * isMobile --%>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
        border="0" 
        style="background-color-obs:#FFFFFF;margin-bottom:0;">
   <tr>
      <td valign="top" width="100%" nowrap="nowrap">
        <div id="mode-ribbon-wrapper">
                <div class="mode-ribbon" style="max-width:100%;">
                    <a href="http://www.dot.gov"><img alt="d o t logo" 
                    src="/CompassThemesURS/themes/html/COMPASS_THEME_URS/images/dot_ribbon_logo.png"><span class="dottext">United States Department of Transportation</span></a>
                                    <ul class="mode-ribbon-links">
                            <li><a href="http://www.dot.gov/about">About DOT</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.dot.gov/our-activities">Our Activities</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.dot.gov/areas-of-focus">Areas of Focus</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="bannerId" valign="top" width="100%" height="90px" nowrap="nowrap"
      style="background-image: url('/CompassThemesURS/themes/html/commonurs/images/FMCSA_URS_banner.png');background-repeat: no-repeat;border-bottom:1px solid black;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

NOTE: I had early on set the trace string "com.ibm.wps.resourceaggregator.CombinerDataSource.RemoteDebug=all" through the Integrated Solutions Console as per article: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRKX_8.0.0/dev/csa2t_trble_tracemod.dita  which causes the portal to load the uncompressed js and css files, to help during configuring of the custom theme, but in an effort to load the faster compressed versions, have now removed that trace string and am seeing errors in Firebug console directly tied to having this trace string removed.  The initial two errors are:

```
GET https://localhost:10060/wps/myportal/urs/U/MaintainFees/!ut/p/a1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOK9LFyMDJ1MDLzcTQzNDBw9TY0tfbzNDS1MDIEKIoEKDHAARwNC-sP1o_ArMYAqwGNFQW6EQaajoiIAxPeRKA!!/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/cldr/nls/number.js 301 Moved Permanently      10ms    ra:coll...head_js (line 15)

GET https://localhost:10060/wps/mycontenthandler/urs/!ut/p/spa/Z6_J8D21B40JG4160AI539LK71841/html/cldr/nls/number.js 404 Not Found      6ms ra:coll...head_js (line 15)
```

Does that make any sense?  How could removing that trace string cause this?

Comment: maybe this one helps on further debugging  https://developer.ibm.com/digexp/docs/docs/themes/debugging-cachability-issues-theme-resource-aggregator-requests/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to that site.  It looks like it could be helpful.  I'll report back what I find out.

Comment: there is one thing I run into, that the theme itself adds informtion to the cachability, but did not find the article where it had been documented. So Portlet, Page and Theme control if the page is cached inside of the browser, and this includes theme artifacts